# Is there a better way to get String[] from an Enum in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I have an enum

```
public enum UnitSystem {
    ImperialSystem("Imperial", "in.", 1),
    MetricSystem("Metric", "cm.", 2.54);
    private String unitSystemName;
    private String lengthSuffix;
    private double lengthCoeff;
```

I am trying to get `String[] l` that would have `{"Imperial", "Metric"};` that is an array containing `unitSystemName` of each system. Right now my best bet is:

```
String[] l = Arrays.stream(UnitSystem.values()).map(UnitSystem::name).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[UnitSystem.values().length]);
```

Is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: If its about fields of the Enum instead of the Enum itself, than that is a good oneliner solution. If you need it on a verry regular basis, you can always choose to store it in a field for easy acces and performance induction.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to go over the enum values **somewhere** and extract the names from them, be it inside the enum's code like Calvin's answer suggests or outside of it like you did. There's no way (at least no way I can think of) to get around this.

You code could be cleaned up a tad, though. there's no reason to collect the stream to a list and then convert it to an array - you could convert it to an array directly:

```
String[] l = 
Arrays.stream(UnitSystem.values()).map(UnitSystem::name).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public enum UnitSystem {
    ImperialSystem("Imperial", "in.", 1),
    MetricSystem("Metric", "cm.", 2.54);

    UnitSystem(String unitSystemName, String lengthSuffix, double lengthCoeff) {
        this.UNITE_SYSTEM_NAME = unitSystemName;
        this.LENGTH_SUFFIX = lengthSuffix;
        this.LENGTH_CO_EFF = lengthCoeff;
    }

    private final String UNITE_SYSTEM_NAME;
    private final String LENGTH_SUFFIX;
    private final double LENGTH_CO_EFF;

    public static String[] getNames() {
        String[] strings = new String[UnitSystem.values().length];
        short count = 0;
        for (UnitSystem s : UnitSystem.values()) {
            strings[count] = s.getName();
            count++;
        }
        return strings;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return UNITE_SYSTEM_NAME;
    }

    public String getLengthSuffix() {
        return LENGTH_SUFFIX;
    }

    public double getLengthCoeff() {
        return LENGTH_CO_EFF;
    }
}
```

By completing the enum with getter methods for each instance of a UnitSystem, we can create a static method that returns a String array of all this enums name data. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a getter for `unitSystemName` and use `toArray(String[]::new)` to convert from `Stream<String>` to `String[]`.

```
public enum UnitSystem {
    ...

    UnitSystem(String unitSystemName, String lengthSuffix, double lengthCoeff) {
        this.unitSystemName = unitSystemName;
        ...
    }

    public String getUnitSystemName() {
        return unitSystemName;
    }

    public static String[] getNames() {
        return Arrays.stream(UnitSystem.values())
                .map(UnitSystem::getUnitSystemName)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a Static array of names will allow them only to be loaded once when the classloader loads the class. If there is any chance you will reference this list more than once it would be ideal.

```
public enum UnitSystem
{
  ImperialSystem("Imperial", "in.", 1), MetricSystem("Metric", "cm.", 2.54);
  private String unitSystemName;

  private String lengthSuffix;

  private double lengthCoeff;

  private static String[] names = Arrays.stream(UnitSystem.values())
      .map(UnitSystem::name).toArray(String[]::new);

  UnitSystem(String unitSystemName, String lengthSuffix, double lengthCoeff)
  {
    this.unitSystemName = unitSystemName;
    this.lengthSuffix = lengthSuffix;
    this.lengthCoeff = lengthCoeff;
  }

  public static String[] getNames()
  {
    return names;
  }

  public String getUnitSystemName()
  {
    return unitSystemName;
  }

  public String getLengthSuffix()
  {
    return lengthSuffix;
  }

  public double getLengthCoeff()
  {
    return lengthCoeff;
  }
}
```